# Business process modeling diagram

Tags: bpmn

Can anyone help me identify the mistake in the diagram?
[image: image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario that will make such process execution stuck in the parallel gateway located right before F task:

- Execute task A
- Execute task B
- Execute task C
- Execute task D
- Execute task E
- Execute task F
- Condition on exclusive gateway lead to execution of the branch going to G task
- Execute task G
- Execute task E

You end up in the parallel gateway located right before F waiting for the transition coming from C task to be active but that will never happen.

So you end up stuck in the parallel gateway.